# JDBC issue with Tomcat 7 and Idea ide

Tags: mysql, apache, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

I am developing an Androip application that is intended to be integrated with some web services(jsp)For this,i am using Intellij Idea 11.1.3 to develop and my web server is Apache Tomcat 7(for the web service).When i try to load mysql driver as `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` it is ok(no exception)but when i do

java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseUrl,"root","root");

some exceptions are thrown as this:

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306/androiddb
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.jsp.add_jsp._jspService(add_jsp.java:78)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

As saying **No suitable Driver found**.But mysql driver(jar file)is attached to my module from *Project Structure->Libraries->New Project Library*.What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is wrong; it should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/androiddb` (note the addition of `//` between `jdbc:mysql:` and `localhost`).

See also [Driver/Datasource Class Names, URL Syntax and Configuration Properties for Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to add the mysql-connectio-java.jar to the lib folder of the your application.
Go to your webapp deployed folder and check if the jar is in the folder WEB-INF/lib

Comment: But there is no folder like that in the project folder.You mean eclipse ide?

Comment: Yes, in eclipse ide it is possible to view/edit the lib folder of the webapp. I am not sure how it is in the intellij idea because never used it. Anyway I just did a quick google search, take a look in the item 8 of this tutorial: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/setting_up_an_intellij.html make sure to add the mysql connector jar file there, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error
Eclipse say that:
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

I used to delete the command Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") but sometime it run properly, sometimes it return blank page - without error

Now I use Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") and it's OK

Comment: This is not an answer to this question. As I answered six (6!) years ago, the problem of the OP had to do with an incorrect JDBC url. The **warning** you get is unrelated.